# MySQL DataCOnnection and ADO.NET

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, ado.net, odbc

I want to use mysqlconnection, command and datareader or sqlconnection, command and datareader based on a condition. I want to use same variables for both type of connection

Ex:

```
Currently i have
dim _c as New mySqlConnection()
dim _cmd as New mysqlCommand()
dim _reader as New mysqlreader()

_reader = _cmd.executereader()
'loop through _reader
 -----------------
```

How can i change first three to use sql/mysql based on select case. Is this possible?

Comment: Because of the "scope" of your definitions inside a CASE or even an IF/THEN you *could* duplicate the definitions using the same variable names... BUT outside the scope the compiler will complain that its not been defined. And you certainly may not create definitions with identical names but different attributes.
You should probably create a dbclass/db_module/db_subroutine which can passback reader-rows of either type. But the work would be hidden in the dbclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. ADO.NET has a provider API for that. You have to do something like this:

```
string providerName;

if (true/*add your logic here*/)
   providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
else
   providerName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();

// ... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that returns the datareader.  Place your select case in the method,  regardless of the conditions you use to build the query, the data reader will be returned.

Make sure you close the data reader when you are done.